# DrawerActivity with Tabs

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation, navigation-drawer

I need help since I'm going crazy. I have a project, which I had already implemented the tabs. Now I want to put the Navigation Drawer.
All I want is that when I select a Drawer menu, I change the tabs, but I don't know how to reference it.
I show the code of the MainActivity:

As you can see, I have already implemented some tabs. And the Drawer Activity. Each item in the Activity drawer calls a fragment, and in turn each tab calls another fragment to display within a ViewPager.

```
class MainActivity : ToolbarActivity() {


private var prevBottomSelected: MenuItem? = null
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    setUpViewPager(getPagerAdapter())
    setUpBottomNavigationBar()

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}


private fun getPagerAdapter(): PagerAdapter{
    val adapter = PagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    adapter.addFragment(InfoFragment())
    adapter.addFragment(RateFragment())
    adapter.addFragment(ChatFragment())
    return adapter
}

private fun setUpViewPager(adapter: PagerAdapter){
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            // Selección de menu inferior, configuracion de como aparecen seleccionados
            if(prevBottomSelected == null){
                bottomNavigation.menu.getItem(0).isChecked = false
            } else {
                prevBottomSelected!!.isChecked = false
            }
            bottomNavigation.menu.getItem(position).isChecked = true
            prevBottomSelected = bottomNavigation.menu.getItem(position)
        }
    })
}

private fun setUpBottomNavigationBar(){
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId){
                R.id.bottom_nav_info -> {
                    viewPager.currentItem = 0; true
                }
                R.id.bottom_nav_rates -> {
                    viewPager.currentItem = 1; true
                }
                R.id.bottom_nav_chat -> {
                    viewPager.currentItem = 2; true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
}}
```

Enter the PageAdapter code. I need that when I press nav_home in the Drawer, different fragments and items appear in the tab.

```
class PagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT){

private val fragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragmentList[position]
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return fragmentList.size
}
fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    fragmentList.add(fragment)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PagerAdapter is abstrace you probebly have your implementation of it that we can't see. I guess that is the cause of the problem. If that is the case try this code for pager adapter:

```
class pagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> InfoFragment()
            1 -> RateFragment()
            2 -> ChatFragment()
            else -> throw RuntimeException("Unsupported fragment position")
        }
    }
    override fun getCount() = 3
}
```

Comment: Edit my post. I need to change the fragments of the tab.